# inverse rule in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, web-config

With this rule, I saying: if url is "domain.com",

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="domain.com" />
```

How about saying: any domain except "domain.com", need something inverse.

```
 <rule name="[RULE NAME]" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="domain.com" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="http://[NEW URL]/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
     </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a answer for my question, just need to add  `negate="true"` like:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="domain.com" negate="true"`/>
```